# Can't parse JSON object with Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a problem with parsing following JSON object:

```
{ 
    "SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0" : 
    {
        "origin" : "SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
        "state" : "connected",
        "friendlyNameLong" : "Camera 3",
        "friendlyNameShort" : "3"
    },
    "SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0" : 
    {
        "origin" : "SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
        "state" : "disconnected",
        "friendlyNameLong" : "Camera 5", 
        "friendlyNameShort" : "5" 
    },
    ...
```

As far as i know, this Server1..., Server2... shouldn't be variables, there should be written "server" or something like that. I am using Newtonsoft.JSON to parse this data but i can't deserialize it. I always get null values. For example, this is my VideoSource class

```
  private class VideoSource
  {
       public string origin { get; set; }
       public string state { get; set; }
       public string friendlyNameLong { get; set; }
       public string friendlyNameShort { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return origin;
       }
   }
```

and I'm trying to parse it with following function:

```
private VideoSource ParseJsonToVideoSource(string obj)
{
    dynamic source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);

    VideoSource s = new VideoSource();
    s.origin = source.origin;
    s.friendlyNameLong = source.friendlyNameLong;
    s.friendlyNameShort = source.friendlyNameShort;
    s.state = source.state;

    return s;
}
```

As I said, i get null values. What's wrong?

Comment: The JSON is an array, not a single object, you need to deserialize it to a list or array. Did you try changing `dynamic` to `var` and looking at what the type is in the debugger? I think `DeserializeObject` returns an object, not a dynamic object.

Comment: @RonBeyer

Yep, it's an array. How would i parse it? When i change to `var`, it says it typeof `object`. When i try to deserialize it like this:

`var source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoSource>(obj);`

I get null values (of course, because it's array of values). I have no idea what to do...

Comment: @RonBeyer: That's not an array. There are no brackets (`[` and `]`). It's just a single object with multiple properties which in turn have properties of their own.

Comment: Which version of Newtonsoft.JSON are you using? Can you try the following line instead and tell us the result? `var source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);`

Comment: When i do as @RonBeyer suggested, i get Object (as type) but it's base is _Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer_. I am using latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    string obj = @"{ 
        ""SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0"" : 
        {
            ""origin"" : ""SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0"",
            ""state"" : ""connected"",
            ""friendlyNameLong"" : ""Camera 3"",
            ""friendlyNameShort"" : ""3""
        },
        ""SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0"" : 
        {
            ""origin"" : ""SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0"",
            ""state"" : ""disconnected"",
            ""friendlyNameLong"" : ""Camera 5"", 
            ""friendlyNameShort"" : ""5"" 
        }
    }";

    VideoSource s = new VideoSource();
    dynamic source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, VideoSource>>(obj);
    foreach(var videoSource in source)
    {
        s.origin = videoSource.Value.origin;
        s.friendlyNameLong = videoSource.Value.friendlyNameLong;
        s.friendlyNameShort = videoSource.Value.friendlyNameShort;
        s.state = videoSource.Value.state;
        s.Dump();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class VideoSource
{
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string friendlyNameLong { get; set; }
    public string friendlyNameShort { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return origin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea i see that i was too slow this time :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be this:

```
dynamic source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
foreach(var videoSource in source)
{
    // Here you can access videoSource.origin, videoSource.state etc.
}
```

An `ExpandoObject` is actually just a dictionary, so you could also deserialize into a dictionary with your `VideoSource` as the value:

```
var videoSources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, VideoSource>>(json);
foreach(var videoSource in source)
{
    // videoSource is of type VideoSource
}
```

(This has already been noted by Mateusz in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867228/cant-parse-json-object-with-newtonsoft-json/30867651#comment49776521_30867534))

Answer (score 0):

I'd form an array out of it like this:

```
[
    {
        "origin": "SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
        "state": "connected",
        "friendlyNameLong": "Camera 3",
        "friendlyNameShort": "3"
    },
    {
        "origin": "SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
        "state": "disconnected",
        "friendlyNameLong": "Camera 5",
        "friendlyNameShort": "5"
    }
]
```

and deserialize it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VideoSource>>(jsonString);
```

Then it should work!

**UPDATE**

When you have no control over your json, do it this way:

```
string json =
            "{\"SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0\":{\"origin\":\"SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0\",\"state\":\"connected\",\"friendlyNameLong\":\"Camera 3\",\"friendlyNameShort\":\"3\"},\"SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0\":{\"origin\":\"SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0\",\"state\":\"disconnected\",\"friendlyNameLong\":\"Camera 5\",\"friendlyNameShort\":\"5\"}}";

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (JProperty property in result)
{
    var myVideoSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoSource>(property.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can't do, service returns data like in my first post... Have to parse it in that form.

Comment: Then try deserializing with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, VideoSource>>(jsonString);`

Comment: I would go with @Mateusz suggestion of using string-VideoSource dictionary. It should deserialize just fine in one line.

Comment: Yes, it works that way @Gerino. Dictionary with string and VideoSource pair. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Your json data is actually list like dictionary key value pair. Key is server name. You can parse like this.

```
        public Dictionary<string, VideoSource> ParseJsonToVideoSource(string obj)
        {
            Dictionary<string, VideoSource> result = new Dictionary<string, VideoSource>();
            dynamic sources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);

            foreach (var source in sources)
            {
                VideoSource s = new VideoSource();
                s.origin = source.Value.origin;
                s.friendlyNameLong = source.Value.friendlyNameLong;
                s.friendlyNameShort = source.Value.friendlyNameShort;
                s.state = source.Value.state;

                result.Add(source.Name, s);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but i think, json has to be like this.

```
[ 
{"name":"SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
"info" :
{
    "origin" : "SERVER1/DeviceIpint.3/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
    "state" : "connected",
    "friendlyNameLong" : "Camera 3",
    "friendlyNameShort" : "3"
}},
{name:"SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
info:
{
    "origin" : "SERVER2/DeviceIpint.5/SourceEndpoint.video:0:0",
    "state" : "disconnected",
    "friendlyNameLong" : "Camera 5", 
    "friendlyNameShort" : "5" 
}}]
```

Comment: Already solved... Also, unfortunately, I don't have control over JSON data. I get it as is, from video server.

Comment: okay, you can use which i wrote. The answer that you checked okay, it ignores server names. My code includes server name as key.

Comment: Yes, solution works and server name is irrelevant since it's stated in "origin" variable. But thanks anyway!